# select sum column and group by with Mongodb and Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, aggregation-framework, jenssegers-mongodb

I have a issue with my query:

[image]

I want to

> SELECT "user_info" with SUM "amount" and GROUP BY "user_id"

I am using Laravel 5 and ***jenssegers/laravel-mongodb***

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

http://laravel.io/forum/10-05-2014-raw-select-using-jenssegers-laravel-mongodb

check link above or use this as i write.

**`$total = DB::table('user_info')->sum('amount')->groupBy('user_id')->get();`**

Comment: Thank Tejas,
If i use MYSQL: 
It like:


    `SELECT user_id, ..., SUM("amount") as total_amount
    FROM table
    WHERE  ... AND ...
    GROUP BY user_id;`


I use your code  and it doesn't work with me.

I have some problem:

`- Field "amount" save by STRING type (can not SUM in normal)`

`- Some WHERE in query.`
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For better performance use the underlying MongoDB driver's aggregation framework methods as this uses the native code on the MongoDB server rather than the `.groupBy()` methods which basically wraps mapReduce methods.

Consider the following aggregation operation which uses the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline and the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** operator to do the sum aggregation:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$user_id",
            "user_info": { "$first": "$user_info" },
            "total": { "$sum": "$amount" }
        }
    }
]);
```

The equivalent Laravel example implementation:

```
$postedJobs = DB::collection('collectionName')->raw(function($collection) {
    return $collection->aggregate(array(
        array(
            "$group" => array(
                "_id" => "$user_id",
                "user_info" => array("$first" => "$user_info")
                "total" => array("$sum" => "$amount")
            )
        )   
    ));
});
```